# I am getting CRON Job String format error while deploying code to to the aws

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, cron, serverless, c3.js

I want to schedule the task for 17:00 PM every day(Monday through Friday). I have following expression. But I am getting "Error: Invalid cron string format
at Cron.fromString......." while deploying to aws

```
...........
events:
  - schedule: 
        rate: cron(0 17 ? * MON-FRI *)
        timezone: Australia/Sydney
```

->  I also tried

```
  events:
  - schedule: 
        rate: cron(0 0 17 ? * MON-FRI *)
        timezone: Australia/Sydney
```

Answer (score 0):

The `cron` expression is wrong.
Should be `cron(0 17 ? * MON-FRI *)`.
You can check them for correctness in Amazon EventBridge:
`Rules -> Create rule -> Schedule pattern`

Comment: I checked on the Rules -> Create rule -> Schedule pattern, still i am getting error

Comment: Did You changed the cron expression? It's only one 0 at the beginning. Keep in mind that the schedule in EventBridge works only in UTC. I dont know how this looks like in other scheduled event services.